# Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'segmentAlongLine'

Tags: python, arcpy, line, cursor, update

I am trying to trim each polyline in a shapefile down to the first 15 feet of each line. The `segmentAlongLine` method was suggested to me, but this code is getting the `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'segmentAlongLine'`.

`SHAPE@` in this case is a polyline object... Why is it calling it a list and why isn't `segmentAlongLine` working? I have found questions about this error but none of the answers seem to apply to my issue.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,"SHAPE@") as cursor:  
    for row in cursor:   
        row.segmentAlongLine(0,15)
```

Comment: print(row) outputs (<Polyline object at 0x161d5c90[0x161d5d60]>,) for each of my 260,000 rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you try:

```
errors = []
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,["SHAPE@", "OID@"]) as cursor:  
    for row in cursor:
        try:
            row[0].segmentAlongLine(0,15)
        except AttributeError:
            errors.append(row)
```

What is in `errors` list?

And you are not changing anything with your code. You need to assign row[0] a new value and cursor.updateRow(row)

Comment: print (errors) outputs [[None, 11035]]

Comment: Then that rows geometry is broken/empty

Comment: Thank you so much. I deleted that record and the script seemed to work successfully (no errors anyway) however... none of the lines actually shortened. The shapefile looks exactly the same. I can't imagine what the problem could be now.

Answer (score 5):

`row` is a list containing the shape of the feature. Use `row[0].segmentAlongLine(0,15)`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and got "Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'segmentAlongLine' ". Any ideas?

Comment: Your list is empty

Comment: @ElizaC it means that the feature has an empty geometry. Because `row[0]` returns `None`.